# Dash doesn't launch Gedit at the first try

Tags: gedit

I'm curious to find out what's going on here.

1. Push the [windows] key --> Dash pops up.
2. Type 'ge' --> 'Text editor' appears.
3. [Enter] --> Nothing happens.

With any other program, it launches the program.

Repeat the steps and gedit launches.

From terminal, gedit doesn't start. In the system monitor, it's 'sleeping'.

This happens in my session, in my wife's session on the same computer, gedit runs.

Any idea why gedit sleeps at the first launch?

Comment: Does this problem persist if you restart the PC?

Comment: possibly you have another script launching gedit?  what is the output of `which gedit` ?  Do you have a custom gedit desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications ?

Comment: @fluteflute, yes, this is happening since some time ago.

Comment: @fossfreedom, /usr/bin/gedit. I don't have any custom gedit file there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm it, it's very annoying.

This was reported as bug [#827414](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/827414) several month ago and is fixed in 12.04 (Precise), don't know if there will be backport to 11.10 (Oneiric).

You can use very simple workaround: run `gedit` always with command line switch `--standalone`. Here is my script for that, it's slightly adapted from [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/827414/comments/33):

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/gedit /usr/bin/gedit.bin
$ sudo bash -c 'echo -e "#"\!"/bin/bash\n/usr/bin/gedit.bin --standalone \"\$@\"" >/usr/bin/gedit'
$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/gedit
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried and it works!